# different steps in jquery ui slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I use [jQuery UI slider](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.11/slider/). I need to change steps in my case. I should have values of line:

```
var values = [0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
```

I don't know how I can do it. I have found [this decision](http://jsfiddle.net/KyKqq/). But here step is 1 and without float values. In my case 0.5 is the first. After that 1 (step 0.5) and then step is 1. How can I do it via js/jquery?

Thank you!

Comment: why not simply let the values go from 0 to 12 with step one, and when you need the actual value treat 0 as 0.5?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You can set the [step](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-step) option, but not to be different between different steps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/KyKqq/473/

```
var sliderValue = [0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 26, 39, 52, 65];

$(function() {
        $( "#slider" ).slider({
            value:[ 0.5 ],      
            min: 0.5,
            max: 65,
            step : 0.5,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
               if( sliderValue.indexOf(ui.value)===-1 ) return false;
               $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value)
            }
        });
        $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
    });
```